# How can I execute sales_order_place_after observer for multiple times for testing purpose

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, event-observer

I want to do some manipulations after placing order want to check for each change in different scenarios to check changes each time I need to place order, is there any other way so that I can execute observer for many times with one order.

Comment: Why you need to call it Multiple Times? It will do same thing right? For Different Events It's Fine

Comment: I want to add some logic over there for development  purpose I want to execute after every code change. Every time it's difficult to  check in `Mage Logs` for whats going on in observer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. get existing order increment ID for example = `145000038`
2. comment out `'sales_order_place_after'` tags in

`app/code/core/Mage/SalesRule/etc/config.xml` and

`app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/config.xml` and

`app/code/core/Enterprise/PageCache/etc/config.xml` (if you run `EE`) to disable existing `sales_order_place_after` observers.

And don't forget to clear cache.

3. run this code

   ```
   <?php
   include('app/Mage.php');
   Mage::app();
   $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId('145000038');
   Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_order_place_after', array('order'=>$order));
   ```

   as many times as you like.

Comment: Good hack @ Konstantin +1 from me :)

Comment: I will check this now :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but may be this extension helps you,

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/yireo-checkouttester.html

Comment: Thanks for the post Keyur Not sure but this won't trigger `sales_order_place_after`  event multiple times it will only triggers `checkout onepage  success`  event.

Answer (score 0):

For Magento 2, We can do it by placing following code in root folder,

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$order = $obj->get('\Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface');
$order->loadByIncrementId('00001952-42');

/** @var \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $manager */
$eventmanager = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface');
$eventmanager->dispatch('sales_order_save_after',  array('order'=>$order));
```